# How to get the conditional count base on a multiple rows with a dax query

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

My requirement is this: I have a table, say OUTBOUNDs.

[image]

Here I want to get the only the completed Stores without pending status. Even when a one-line item is pending it cannot be considered as a completed store. The output must be 1 (Store 'C'.)

This is what I did with my DAX query so far, problem is when I run this it returns not only completed, half completed stores as well.

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(OUTBOUND [Store]),FILTER(OUTBOUND,[ Complete Status] = 1 && [Pending Status]= 0))
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible approach:

```
Count = SUMX(
            SUMMARIZE(OUTBOUND,
                OUTBOUND[Store],
                "Completed", MIN(OUTBOUND[Complete Status]),
                "Pending", NOT(MAX(OUTBOUND[Pending Status]))),
            [Completed] * [Pending])
```

This gives you the count of stores where the `[Complete Status]` is all `1` and the `[Pending Status]` does not have any `1` values.